# Recreated database or clear all data on import to it in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to recreate *db* during import of the dump? 
By recreate, *db* drop or deletion of its data is meant.

```
mysql db -u root -p < dump.sql
```

It's possible of course to drop and create db manually or automate it using bash, but as import is run frequently, i would like it to be done automatically via *mysql* command if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this mysql command in order to drop and create database in a dump script:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `database_name`;
CREATE DATABASE `database_name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump ... --add-drop-database ...
```

Check out the vast number of other options, too.